# How to define a function using psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2

This is my first question here, so thanks in advance to anyone replying to this humble student.

I'm trying to define a function using psycopg2. I have split into two stages. First the parameters necessary for connection, which I managed to read through documentation and solve. Now, my issue is dealing with the query to pass it through the function. Ex:

```
def databasequery(database, user, password, host, port): 
            psycopg2.connect( 
            database=database, 
            user=user, 
            password=password, 
            host=host, 
            port=port, 
        ) 
 
conn = get_connection() 
  
curr = conn.cursor() 
  
print(databasequery("Select * from customers", "your_database","your_user","your_password","your_host","your_port"))
```

How can I add the query to pass through the function?

Comment: You don't write a function "using `psycopg2`". That doesn't make sense. It's a library in itself with its own functions that you use in your code.  `psycopg2.connect()` returns an actual connection object that you need to either a) use in your function or b) return from that function and reference it somewhere outside. You're missing some fundamentals of python functions here that will be severely complicated by jumping straight to `psycopg2`

Comment: To follow on what @roganjosh said: the psycopg2 documentation is going to assume you know things that you do not know. Library documentation basically never does hand-holding for neophytes and even psycopg2 tutorials are going to assume you already have a soldi grasp of the fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

Make suitable changes as needed

```
import psycopg2

def create_function(sql_query):
    try:
        # Connect to your PostgreSQL database
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            dbname="your_database",
            user="your_username",
            password="your_password",
            host="your_host",
            port="your_port"
        )
        # Create a cursor object
        cur = conn.cursor()
        
        # Execute the SQL query to create the function
        cur.execute(sql_query)
        
        # Commit the transaction
        conn.commit()

        # Close the cursor and connection
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
        
        print("Function created successfully")

    except psycopg2.Error as e:
        print("Error:", e)


# Example usage: Define the SQL query for the function
sql_query = """
Select * from customers", "your_database","your_user","your_password","your_host","your_port
"""

# Call the function to create the function
create_function(sql_query)
```

Comment: Be very careful (CC @JaredSmith) that context managers don't work [the way you expect with `psycopg2`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#with-statement). See the red warning box

Comment: @roganjosh wow thanks for that, I haven't used psycopg2 in the last few years and I either forgot that or missed it entirely.

Comment: @JaredSmith you're welcome; now you won't crash the entire company database after explicitly telling everyone to use context managers to be sure connections are closed :P Stale connections will age away naturally but if you get a tipping point where the stale connections are created too fast and exceed ~500 or ~600, everything goes boom... the problem can lie dormant for a long time because of this "silent" balancing act. Painful lesson indeed.